# alternating arduino outputs based on if statement

Tags: for-loop, arduino

This is my first post on stackoverflow and one of my first arduino projects. Thanks for your help.

I am building a relay controller that alternates which battery is being charged based on an LED indicator light. I'm getting close, but I am having difficulty with the control logic.

I am able to read the LED and determine when the battery should be switched (my boolean variable says switch or don't). It also seems that a for statement is the best way to proceed to the next output. I found this example but it doesn't quite fit: http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ForLoop

Looking for these states: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ue192ebrhng3xcw/relaystates.jpg?dl=0

This is my first attempt:

`for (int thisPin = 9; relayswitch = true; thisPin++){ 
    // turn the last pin off:
    digitalWrite(thisPin-1, LOW);

    delay(2);

    // turn the next pin on:
    digitalWrite(thisPin, HIGH);

  }
  //resets relay switch indicator
  boolean relayswitch = false;`

Comment: How many different charging circuits do you have? What is the condition that needs to be meet to change over?

Comment: One charging circuit with alternating battery outputs. The relay switches when the LED indicator hasn't flashed for 60 seconds. Thanks! Josh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is your question?

One answer might be: you have implemented an endless loop.

```
for (...; relayswitch = true; ...){ 
    // code that will not alter relayswitch
}
```

Notice that you do NOT check for a condition with the assignment operator "=". A condition would be checked with "==". Thus the "while condition" of the for loop will be true no matter what you do in the body of the loop. However even if you would check with "==" it would not matter as you do not alter this variable inside the loop.

Comment: Thank you! Not sure that I would have figured out my mistake without your help.